# How to send the selected item in the listWidget to another function as a parameter

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

Whenever I click any function in the list widget, it ran a specific function. Now I want to send the item itself, as a parameter to that function. Here is the code:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.listWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL("itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *)"), self.test)

def test(self):
    print 'hello'
```

Instead I want:

```
def test(self,item):
        print item
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That should already work - when `itemClicked` is emitted it sends the clicked `QListWidgetItem` as a parameter. You just need to edit your `test` function to accept an extra parameter, and that will be your `QListWidgetItem`.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt
from PyQt4.QtGui import QListWidget, QListWidgetItem, QApplication

import sys

class MyList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QListWidget.__init__(self)
        self.add_items()
        self.itemClicked.connect(self.item_click)

    def add_items(self):
        for item_text in ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']:
            item = QListWidgetItem(item_text)
            self.addItem(item)

    def item_click(self, item):
        print item, str(item.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    myList = MyList()
    myList.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the above example you'll see a QListWidget with three items. When you click an item the item along with the item's text will be printed to the console.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more question for you, is it possible to give different colors(two) for different line in textEdit. For example BLACK,GREY. Each row has a different color.

Comment: For QTextEdit? You'd be best posting this as a separate question to keep things on topic and make it easier for other people with the same question to find. If you're talking about different coloured rows in your QTableWidget you can call .setAlternatingRowColors(True) on your QTableWidget to have the background colour of the rows alternate.